# How to replace text in Sublime without moving the cursor or viewport

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text to find some text in a file and make some changes to it, using the "Replace" command.

When the thing I want to change is selected, if I click the "Replace" button, pick the "Selection → Replace Next" command, or press Command + Option + E, the editor makes the appropriate change, and then moves the cursor to the next occurrence. This is especially annoying if the next occurrence is far below where the replacement is made, because the viewport immediately scrolls down to the next occurrence, without giving me a chance to see the replacement, make sure it was done correctly, and manually correct it if necessary, without having to scroll back up and look for it.

Is there any command or trick to do the replacement on the selected text and *not* move the cursor? I would prefer if it leaves the replacement text selected.

Answer (score 1):

When using Sublime on a PC and navigating the search results from either the "Find > Find..." or "Find > Replace..." menus, I like to use the function key `F3` or `Shift + F3` to navigate forward or back of all the found results.  Perhaps this paging works on a Mac too?

If I find an item that I do want to replace, then I use `Ctrl + Shift + H` (`Command + Option + E` on a Mac?) to replace and find next.

**Note for Mac users:** In the past, I've had to change my keyboard to use all F1,F2... keys as Function keys use them in editors or IDE's. You may need to use the `Fn + F3` instead of just the `F3` key above (or change the [keyboard settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/how-to-use-f1-f12-keys-with-macbook) if you plan on using it a lot ).

Comment: I know how to replace and find next. I am looking for a way to replace and do nothing else.

Comment: If you had the replacement text in your clipboard, could you just instead paste its contents to overwrite the selected text?  Then use you could use your search shortcuts to find the next instance you wanted to replace.  Not exactly what you were looking for, but perhaps a usable workaround.

Comment: I sometimes do that. It works fine if it is a simple string, but it doesn't work if it has references to things captured by a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text around your test target and click the **In selection** button.

[image: In selection button in Sublime Text 3's Replace Dialog]

Now it will be the only match and there won't be another to jump to.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am not sure how practical that would be, especially if I am working in a big file with lots of things I want to replace.